# Unflattening a data structure with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

This is not a homework question. Feel free to recommend a better place to post this if necessary.

Given the following data structure:

```
class Thing
{
    public Thing() 
    {
        this.Things = new List<Thing>();
    }
    public string First { get; set; }

    public string Group { get; set; }

    public List<Thing> Things { get; set; }
}
```

And the following data:

```
var data = new List<Thing>
{
    new Thing { First = "Alex", Group = "Sams" },
    new Thing { First = "John", Group = "Sams" },
    new Thing { First = "", Group = "Sams" },
    new Thing { First = "Sue", Group = "Freds" },
};
```

What's the LINQiest way to re-shape that into a List that looks like this:

```
First = "", Group = Sams
    First = Alex, Group = Sams
    First = John, Group = Sams
First = Sue, Group = Freds
```

Some things to note:

- Note that **Thing** can contain a list of Things.
- Where no **First** is specified, that is assumed to be a parent, and all records containing a **First** with the same **Group** are children.
- Records with no parent per the rule above, are considered parents.

This example shows the desired result:

```
var result = data.Where(p => p.First == "").Select(p => 
{
    p.Things = data.Where(f => f.Group == p.Group).ToList();
    return p;
}).ToList();

result.AddRange(data.Except(result.SelectMany(f => f.Things)).ToList());
```

This also achieves the desired result, but feels a bit long..

```
var result = data
    .GroupBy(p => p.Group)
    .SelectMany(p => p.Where(f => f.First == "" || p.Count() == 1))
    .Select(p => new Thing { First = p.First, Group = p.Group, Things = data
        .Where(f => f.Group == p.Group && f.First != "" && p.First != f.First).ToList() });
```

Comment: Is there only 1 level or multiple levels of things?

Comment: Well, parent and child, but nothing deeper than that.

Comment: Yes, I've tried many things, but it would fill up many pages here just showing off my other attempts. I know of a hundred ways to do this.. just curious what other people think is the best way.

Comment: How do you expect a list to be indented like that? I'm not sure what the output format is meant to be? Are they objects or text output?

Comment: You should at least show on of your failed attempts. Something that you think was your best attempt perhaps. It helps us to answer immensely.

Comment: Your question is confusing. I get now that you're trying to build your structure. But the source data is ambiguous. What if you don't have a `Thing` with `First == ""` but you have multiple "children" with the same `Group` and what if you have many?

Comment: Your solution that you added looks good. Is there something about it that you don't like?

Comment: It feels like it could be done in a single statement, rather than two.  And the first Select seems strange.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be pretty good:

```
var result =
    data
        .Where(p => p.First != "")
        .GroupBy(p => p.Group)
        .Select(gps =>
            gps.Count() == 1
            ? gps.First()
            : new Thing()
            {
                First = "",
                Group = gps.Key,
                Things = gps.ToList(),
            })
        .ToList();
```

This basically ignores all existing things that have `First == ""` and then groups all of the remaining things by `Group`. It then rebuilds the list with a new parent where the groups have more than one thing.

---

Here's the alternative that is a little more robust in circumstances where there are "parent" objects with no children:

```
var result2 =
    data
        .GroupBy(p => p.Group)
        .Select(gps =>
            gps.Count() == 1
            ? gps.First()
            : new Thing()
            {
                First = "",
                Group = gps.Key,
                Things =
                    gps
                        .Where(p => p.First != "")
                        .ToList(),
            })
        .ToList();
```

---

Here's a third, more robust option:

```
var result3 =
    data
        .OrderBy(p => p.First)
        .GroupBy(p => p.Group)
        .Select(gps =>
            gps
                .Skip(1)
                .Aggregate(
                    gps
                        .Select(p => new Thing()
                        {
                            First = p.First,
                            Group = p.Group
                        })
                        .First(),
                    (a, x) =>
                    {
                        a.Things.Add(x);
                        return a;
                    }))
        .ToList();
```

---

We can also add this constructor to `Thing`:

```
public Thing(IEnumerable<Thing> things)
{
    this.Things = new List<Thing>(things);
}
```

And now this works:

```
var result4 =
(
    from p in data.OrderBy(p => p.First).GroupBy(p => p.Group)
    let f = p.First()
    select new Thing(p.Skip(1)) { First = f.First, Group = f.Group }
).ToList();
```

Comment: This also works and is pretty smart. Nice thinking out side of the box.

Comment: +1 well done.  I thought this would cause multiple enumeration of the groupby IEnumerable but R# doesn't think so and I can't think of a way to test whether it does or not.  Using the GroupBy selectResults  function definitely does.

Answer (score 0):

Functional without error checking or other considerations.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new List<Thing> { new Thing { First = "Alex", Group = "Sams" }, new Thing { First = "John", Group = "Sams" }, new Thing { First = "", Group = "Sams" }, new Thing { First = "Sue", Group = "Freds" } };

        var results = from item in data
                      group item by item.Group into g
                      select g;

        List<Thing> list = new List<Thing>();
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            if (item.Count() > 1)
            {
                Thing parent = item.Where(x => String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.First)).First();
                parent.First = "";
                parent.Group = item.First().Group;
                parent.Things = item.Where(x => x != parent).ToList();
                list.Add(parent);
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add(item.First());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One statement yes... more efficient no due to multiple enumerations...

```
var unflattenedList = data.GroupBy(thing => thing.Group, thing => thing, 
    (key, things) => new Thing()
    {
        First = things.Count() == 1 ? things.First().First : string.Empty, 
        Group = key,
        Things = things.Count() == 1 ? null : 
                     things.Where(t => t.First != string.Empty).ToList(),
    });
```

**EDIT:**
The following is what I would use however.. since this eliminates the mutltiple enumeration issues with the above solution.

Your LINQ is like this...

```
var unflattenedList = data.GroupBy(thing => thing.Group, thing => thing, GetThing);
```

And your method that returns a new Thing is here...

```
private static Thing GetThing(string key, IEnumerable<Thing> things)
{
    var thingList = things.ToList();
    return new Thing()
    {
        First = thingList.Count() == 1 ? thingList.First().First : string.Empty, 
        Group = key,
        Things = thingList.Count() == 1 ? null : 
                        thingList.Where(t => t.First != string.Empty).ToList(),
    };
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fit the requirements because it includes the parent Sams rows as a child of itself. So the Sams parent should only have two children.

Comment: That fixed it. The biggest difference in output between this and my last example in the OP is that your Freds row contains a null child collection. No big deal, really. What's your personal preference between yours and mine?

Comment: Neither... I would write a small method that turns the group into a new Thing()